# How to deal with trycatch block and generic in axios

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I have a question about Axios and typescript. The problem is about returning errors because I get the Type error that Promise is not of type number | undefined. It comes from the catch block, How can I handle this case elegantly?

```
export async function getProducts(): Promise<GetProductsResponse> {
    try {
        const response = await productsClient.get<ApiResponse<GetProductsResponse>>('/get-product')
        return  response.data.body.data
    } catch (error) {
       const axiosError = error as AxiosError
       return axiosError.response?.status
       
    }
   
}
```

types

```
export interface GetProductsResponse {
    products: Product[];
    pagesCount: number; 
    totalProducts: string
}

export interface ApiResponse<T> {
    body: {
        data: T;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for precision of the answer, can you show us the definition of `GetProductsResponse`?

Comment: Yeah I can do that :) @niceman

Answer (score 1):

Change your `return` value type to `Promise<GetProductsResponse | number | undefined>`

This `number | undefined` comes from the fact that in case of error, you return `axiosError.response?.status`, which can be either `undefined` (in case of `axiosError.response` being undefined) or `number` (when `axiosError.response` is defined and its `.status` is returned).

Other way to solve this issue if you want to omit `Promise<GetProductsResponse | number | undefined>`, is to return the whole `axiosError` object and change `return` type of your function to `Promise<GetProductsResponse | AxiosError>`

Comment: this answer is wrong, inside an async function the type of what is returned is the type parameter inside promise so when status is returned the return type is `Promise<number | undefined | GetProductsResponse>` not `Promise<GetProductsResponse> | number | undefined`

Comment: @niceman You are right, I have corrected my answer